# Struggling with SQLAlchemy and foreignkey

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm struggling with SQLAlchemy and foreignkeys. I don't know why i'm getting this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column '('workers',).planning_id' could not find table 'planning' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Here is my code:

```
class Workers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workers",
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32), default=lambda: str(uuid4))
    first_name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(500), nullable=True)
    last_name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(500), nullable=True)
    job_uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32), default=lambda: str(uuid4), nullable=True)
    arrival_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, nullable=True)
    updated_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, nullable=False)
    created_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, nullable=False)
    planning_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, ForeignKey("planning.id"))


# Parent
class Planning(Base):
    __tablename__ = "planning",
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32), default=lambda: str(uuid4))
    day = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)
    job_uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32), default=lambda: str(uuid4), nullable=True)
    worker_uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32), default=lambda: str(uuid4))
    created_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime)
    updated_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime)
    schedule = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.JSON)
    workers = relationship("Workers", backref="planning")
```

Comment: You have to define `Planning` first.

Comment: Unfortunaly that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just found where was the problem. It was the comma after the **tablename**.

Comment: the question should just be closed as a typo.